# Libsvm model file format No model number

Tags: machine-learning, svm, libsvm, document-classification, svmlight

I am using libsvm for document classification. I use svm.cc and svm.h in my project. I then call svm_train. I save the model in a file using svm_save_model.

I have there categories. The svm model file is:

```
svm_type c_svc
kernel_type rbf
gamma 0.001002
nr_class 3
total_sv 9
rho -0.000766337 0.00314423 0.00387654
label 0 1 2
nr_sv 3 3 3
SV
1 1 1:0.001 2:0.001 3:0.012521912 5:0.001 15:0.012521912 17:0.012521912 23:0.001 
1 1 1:0.001 2:0.014176543 4:0.093235799 6:0.001 7:0.0058630699 9:0.040529628 10:0.001 
1 1 11:0.38863495 33:0.08295242 46:0.041749886 58:0.08295242 89:0.08295242 127:0.15338862 -1 1 5:0.001 8:0.0565 10:0.001 13:0.001 18:0.0565 21:0.021483399 34:0.12453384 36:0.001 
-1 1 13:0.034959612 34:0.090130132 36:0.034959612 45:0.034959612 47:0.12019824 
-1 1 5:0.001 8:0.048037273 13:0.001 18:0.048037273 29:0.14715472 30:0.018360058 36:0.001 
-1 -1 9:0.0049328688 12:0.090902344 18:0.1156038 27:0.0049328688 31:0.015144206
```

What are 1 and -1 before the vector values in the form of index:value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the libsvm FAQ:

> Q: Can you explain more about the model file?
>
> In the model file,
>   after parameters and other informations such as labels , each line
>   represents a support vector. Support vectors are listed in the order
>   of "labels" shown earlier. (i.e., those from the first class in the
>   "labels" list are grouped first, and so on.) If k is the total number
>   of classes, **in front of a support vector in class j, there are k-1
>   coefficients y*alpha where alpha are dual solution of the following
>   two class problems:  1 vs j, 2 vs j, ..., j-1 vs j, j vs j+1, j vs
>   j+2, ..., j vs k  and y=1 in first j-1 coefficients, y=-1 in the
>   remaining k-j coefficients**. For example, if there are 4 classes, the
>   file looks like:

```
 +-+-+-+--------------------+ 
 |1|1|1|                    | 
 |v|v|v|  SVs from class 1  | 
 |2|3|4|                    |
 +-+-+-+--------------------+ 
 |1|2|2|                    | 
 |v|v|v|  SVs from class 2  | 
 |2|3|4|                    |
 +-+-+-+--------------------+ 
 |1|2|3|                    | 
 |v|v|v|  SVs from class 3  | 
 |3|3|4|                    |
 +-+-+-+--------------------+ 
 |1|2|3|                    | 
 |v|v|v|  SVs from class 4  | 
 |4|4|4|                    |
 +-+-+-+--------------------+
```

http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/faq.html#f402

Comment: yaa, i peeked into the code and found it prints sv_coef[i][j]. Thanks

Comment: actually this picture confused me. As it is not like model file. One understands its significance only after one understands the above comment completely.