# Saving libsvm model structure from matlab to .model file which can be read in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, libsvm

I have 2 questions:

1. I followed the instructions in the post [Lib svm, how to convert MyModel.mat to MyModel.model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744244/lib-svm-how-to-convert-mymodel-mat-to-mymodel-model)
   I tried to build the svm_savemodel.c on Mac OSx El Capitan using:
   mex svm_savemodel.c and the following happened:

Building with 'Xcode with Clang'. Error using mex Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_matlab_matrix_to_model", referenced from: _mexFunction in svm_savemodel.o "_svm_free_and_destroy_model", referenced from: _mexFunction in svm_savemodel.o "_svm_save_model", referenced from: _mexFunction in svm_savemodel.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Can anyone suggest some solution?

2. So I was thinking of writing a matlab code which will convert the model structure in matlab to MyModel.model file which can be read in C++
   This post [Libsvm model file format No model number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18223756/libsvm-model-file-format-no-model-number) talks about the parameters that need to be saved in the .model file.

I am working on regression problem, so in my case the label entry will not be present. Is there anything I need to take care of apart from that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the code at [How to create training data for libsvm (as an svm_node struct)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293332/how-to-create-training-data-for-libsvm-as-an-svm-node-struct) for regression and saw the format in which the model is getting saved

{
struct svm_parameter param;     // set by parse_command_line
struct svm_problem prob;        // set by read_problem
//struct svm_model *model;
struct svm_node *x_space;

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
char input_file_name[1024];
char model_file_name[1024] = "MyModel" ;
const char *error_msg;

param.svm_type = EPSILON_SVR;
param.eps = 1e-3;
param.C = 1;
//param.kernel_type = RBF;
param.degree = 3;


//Problem definition-------------------------------------------------------------
prob.l = 8;

//x values matrix of xor values
double matrix[prob.l][2];
matrix[0][0] = 0.1;
matrix[0][1] = 0.2;

matrix[1][0] = 0.2;
matrix[1][1] = 0.3;

matrix[2][0] = 0.4;
matrix[2][1] = 0.5;

matrix[3][0] = 0.8;
matrix[3][1] = 0.9;

matrix[4][0] = 0.6;
matrix[4][1] = 0.7;

matrix[5][0] = 0.55;
matrix[5][1] = 0.65;

matrix[6][0] = 0.45;
matrix[6][1] = 0.55;

matrix[7][0] = 0.65;
matrix[7][1] = 0.75;

svm_node** x = Malloc(svm_node*,prob.l);

//Trying to assign from matrix to svm_node training examples
for (int row = 0;row <prob.l; row++){
    svm_node* x_space = Malloc(svm_node,3);
    for (int col = 0;col < 2;col++){
        x_space[col].index = col;
        x_space[col].value = matrix[row][col];
    }
    x_space[2].index = -1;      //Each row of properties should be terminated with a -1 according to the readme
    x[row] = x_space;
}

prob.x = x;

//yvalues
prob.y = Malloc(double,prob.l);
prob.y[0] = 0.15;
prob.y[1] = 0.25;
prob.y[2] = 0.45;
prob.y[3] = 0.85;
prob.y[4] = 0.65;
prob.y[5] = 0.6;
prob.y[6] = 0.5;
prob.y[7] = 0.7;

//Train model---------------------------------------------------------------------
svm_model *model = svm_train(&prob,&param);
//svm_model *model = svm_load_model(model_file_name);

//Test model----------------------------------------------------------------------
svm_node* testnode = Malloc(svm_node,3);
testnode[0].index = 0;
testnode[0].value = 0.6;
testnode[1].index = 1;
testnode[1].value = 0.7;
testnode[2].index = -1;

//This works correctly:
double retval = svm_predict(model,testnode);

    svm_save_model(model_file_name, model);
printf("retval: %f\n",retval);


svm_destroy_param(&param);
free(prob.y);
free(prob.x);
free(x_space);

return 0;
```

}
}

Then I wrote the code below in matlab to save the svm model struct generated in matlab and I could read the saved model in C++

{
load('ClassificationMATLAB.mat'); % opens the mat file with svm struct of model, variable name of struct is 'svm'
fid=fopen('Mymodel','w');

fprintf(fid,'%s %s\n','svm_type','epsilon_svr');
fprintf(fid,'%s %s\n','kernel_type','rbf');    % rbf
fprintf(fid,'%s %s\n','nr_class','2'); 
% fprintf(fid,'%s %s\n','degree', '3');

fprintf(fid,'%s %s\n','total_sv',num2str(svm.totalSV));
fprintf(fid,'%s %s\n','rho',num2str(svm.rho));

fprintf(fid,'%s\n','SV');

FullSVs=full(svm.SVs);

for i=1:length(svm.SVs)

```
fprintf(fid, '%s', num2str(svm.sv_coef(i)));
fprintf(fid, '%s %s\n', [' 0:' num2str(FullSVs(i,1))],[' 1:' num2str(FullSVs(i,2))]);
```

end
fclose(fid);

}